# Is the localization of intersection of modules equal to the intersection of appropriate localizations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, localization

Given a commutative unital ring $R$, and a multiplicative subset $S\subseteq R$, I know that for two $R$-submodules $M_1,M_2$ of $M$, we have:

(I) $S^{-1}M_1 \cap S^{-1}M_2= S^{-1}(M_1\cap M_2)$

(II) $S^{-1}M_1+S^{-1}M_2=S^{-1}(M_1+M_2)$

My question is does this also hold for infinite intersections and sums. I am pretty sure that a sum of localizations is equal to the localization of the sum, simply because every element in a sum of modules can be discussed within a finite sum. I suspect that this is untrue for the intersection, but I could not think of a counter-example.

Comment: No for intersections it does not hold. See (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/293224/localization-and-intersection). At the moment I can't think of a simpler counterexample. Also helpful to know that localization seen as a functor commutes with all colimits  but only with finite limits .  For example $\prod_{n \geq 2} (\mathbb{Q} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}/n)$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} (\prod_{n \geq 2} \mathbb{Z}/n) $.

Comment: Try the submodules $n\mathbb Z$ of $\mathbb Z$, $n > 0$, and the multiplicative set $S= \mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: @user26857 Very simple. Nice!

Comment: @user26857 Just to be sure, in your example $S^{-1}(n\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Q}$, and the intersection of the submodules is simply $(0)$?

Comment: Correct.${}{}{}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As suggested by user26857 the counter example for the question is:

For the $\mathbb{Z}$-modules $M_n=n\mathbb{Z}$, and the multiplicative set $S=\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{ 0\}$ we have:

$S^{-1}\big( M_n \big)=\mathbb{Q}$,  $\quad \underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty}{\bigcap}} M_n=(0) \quad$ and $\quad S^{-1}\big( 0 \big)=(0)\subseteq \mathbb{Q}$.

Therefore:

$\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty}{\bigcap}} S^{-1}M_n=\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty}{\bigcap}}\mathbb{Q}=\mathbb{Q}\neq (0)=S^{-1}\Big( \underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty}{\bigcap}}M_n \Big)$